# Monitor doesn't detect my Raspberry pi 3

Tags: pi-3, hdmi, display, kali

I tried to install Kali on my Rpi. 
So, I downloaded the adapted build on offensive security (kali 2.1.2).

The rpi boot without issues, i can access to it via ssh. 
However, my monitor doesn't detect the rpi.(looks like sleeping mode)
I tried different monitor, cable and even with an hdmi to vga converter but the problem Is still here. I have also an 3A power supply.

Comment: are there any errors logged in `dmesg` ?

Comment: Nothing interesting, here is a pastbin: http://pastebin.com/sjtbwJfk

Comment: Try adding `hdmi_safe=1` to `config.txt` (in the first partition, probably mounted on `/boot`; I'm not familiar with Kali) and reboot.

Comment: There is no config.txt on the 1st partition like on rapsbian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by installing rasp-config via dpkg. 
Then I launched raps-config and selected boot to desktop.
Thanks to all for help

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend trying the following

- if you have a spare card, try flashing the standard raspbian and see if it the display comes up. if it does, then the problem might be specific to the kali distro (given you are able to ssh in, i dont think it a case where the disk was incorrectly prepared)
- if the display doesnt come up, it might be some compatibility issue -

  - could be that the distro hasnt been setup to output to hdmi. see [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/53459/33810) post for some insight
  - could be some as simple as the monitor resolution may not be supported or configured properly (try selecting source using the buttons on the monitor).
  - according to [this](https://www.element14.com/community/thread/41563/l/no-hdmi-signal?displayFullThread=true) not all adapters are supported which might explain why the converter didnt work.

Comment: I had been using raspbian and the display was working(with the hdmi cable and also with the vga converter. Maybe the distro isn't setup to output to hdmi. However the version I downloaded is adapted for rpi 2-3.